# Title customization

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to customize a title? I want it to have a red background, but I'm not seeing any way to do it. If there is a simple way to do that that would be great!

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div title="Hi!" class="box">Hi!</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better? your card is red...

Comment: What exactly you want customize? BEcause your Title Background is red?

Comment: I should have worded my question a bit better, but what I was referring was the title that pops up when you hover on the red box, and is there a way to apply a background color to that.

Comment: In the div element the title="Hi!"

Comment: You might want to look for "tooltips" in CSS. You will find many examples for what you want.

Comment: That is pretty close to what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pseudo element and show it on hover.

Example

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "Hi!";
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.box:hover:before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hi!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
    .box {
      width: max-content;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .box:hover {
      background-color:red;
      color:black;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="box">Hi!</div>
```